# How to dispatch a props from a button with React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component with 4 buttons, each with a different color. I want them to dispatch the color to the global state, so I can use it in other components. Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/TeamChoice.css';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { setColorTeam } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class TeamChoice extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    setColor(color) {
        this.props.onClickSetColor(color);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <content className="TeamChoice-content">
                <h1>Choose a team</h1>
                <div className="teamColors">
                    <Button className="blueTeam" onClick={() => this.setColor('blue')} href="/choix-nombre">
                        Team blue
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="redTeam" onClick={() => this.setColor('red')} href="/choix-nombre">
                        Team red
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="teamColors">
                    <Button className="greenTeam" onClick={() => this.setColor('green')} href="/choix-nombre">
                        Team green
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="yellowTeam" onClick={() => this.setColor('yellow')} href="/choix-nombre">
                        Team yellow
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </content>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onClickSetColor: (color) => dispatch(setColorTeam(color)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TeamChoice);
```

Here is the action :

```
export function setColorTeam(color) {
    return {
        type: actions.SETCOLORTEAM,
        color: color,
    };
```

And the reducer :

```
import { actions } from '../actions';

const defaultState = {
    colorTeam: undefined,
};

export function reducers(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SETCOLORTEAM:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { colorTeam: action.color });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I can't see why my property colorTeam stays undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why it didn't work. I use react-router-dom to navigate through my app and the `<Button>` component from react-bootstrap seems not to work in this configuration. So I built a Button component :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export function Button({ className, text, href, param, onClick }) {
    return (
        <>
            <button className={className} onClick={() => onClick(param)}>
                <Link className="linkButton" to={href}>
                    {text}
                </Link>
            </button>
        </>
    );
}

Button.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string, // Le className du bouton pour pouvoir le modifier en css.
    texte: PropTypes.string, // Le texte affiché sur le bouton.
    param: PropTypes.string, // Le paramètre qui sera transmis lors du clic sur le bouton.
    onClick: PropTypes.func, // La fonction qui permet de prendre en compte le clic sur le bouton.
};

export default Button;
```

I wanted to use the `<a>` tag, but it didn't work either with react-router-dom : when navigating through the app, it reloaded the state with the initial state. In the react-router-dom doc, it's explained that you must use the `<Link>` component to make it work, so I did. And now it works !

Answer (score 0):

`setColor` doesn't appear to have `this` correctly bound to it. Bind `this` in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.setColor = this.setColor.bind(this);
}

setColor(color) {
  this.props.onClickSetColor(color);
}
```

or convert it to arrow function

```
setColor = color => this.props.onClickSetColor(color);
```

or forego the proxy function altogether and use the `props.onClickSetColor` callback directly

```
<Button
  className="blueTeam"
  onClick={() => this.props.onClickSetColor('blue')}
  href="/choix-nombre"
>
  Team blue
</Button>
```

Comment: @FabienDelmotte Where are you consuming (i.e. importing) `TeamChoice`? Are you using the default export (`import TeamChoice from '...'`) or the named export (`import { TeamChoice } from '...'`)? The default export is the one connected to your redux store.

Comment: I use the default export : ```import TeamChoice from './components/TeamChoice';```